# What is the process to create a Deadlock?

Tags: algorithm, memory, operating-system, traffic

I have seen many answers on StackOverflow on how to create a Deadlock, but are written code.
I'm looking to understand on a more simple way. I wanted to know which would be the steps you would take to recreate this Deadlock. I'm not looking for codes, but more steps.
[Traffic Deadlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKSUL.gif)

Thank you for your time.
Sorry for the link image, I need 10 reputation to post images.

Answer (score 1):

We've both got a steak to eat, but we're low on silverware.

I've got a fork to eat it with, but you've got the only knife, so I have to wait for you to finish with it before I can cut my meat.

You've got a knife to cut it with, but I've got the only fork, so you have to wait until I'm done before you can grab the fork to hold it down.

Looks like we're gonna go hungry.  That's a deadlock.

The standard solution is just to make sure that if anyone ever needs a knife and a fork at the same time, then they have to pick up the fork first.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way possible - **Process A** has to wait for **process B** to finish first, in order for **A** to finish it's job (let's say **A** needs the output of **B** for some calculation of its own) and the same thing happens in **B**: it has to wait for the output of process **A** in order to finish itself.

I hope this is clear enough for you. Since you specifically asked for no code, I won't write any code since it's probably too easy to find deadlock code. But basically, it's similar as in the picture of cars blocking each other.

Answer (score 0):

The "lock" in deadlock came from the ability to lock files or database tables to prevent multiple processes from updating the same file/table at the same time.

For example, process 1 locks table A and process 2 locks table B.  If process 1 wants to also update table B but finds it locked, then it has to wait for process 2 to release it.  If process 2 has to update table A, it would also be locked out.

This situation is a deadlock where both processes are waiting on each other to release their locks.